# Is there a way to link a vue popup-modal repo with a different create-vue-app repo?

Tags: javascript, git, vue.js, popup

I have two Vue repositories. One repo has code using Vue CDN and is for a Popup modal. The other repo is a Vue project created with 'create-vue' (lets call it the main project). I want to integrate the popup modal into the main project. I want to create a button in the main project and link it to the popup modal. Any suggestions on how to link both the repos or proceed.

Sample popup modal - 'https://codepen.io/chsind/pen/jOaZwRx'

Sample Vue project - 'https://codesandbox.io/s/sample-vue-project-6gkx21'

Thank you for your help in advance :)

Comment: What does "link [two repositories together]" even *mean?* A Git repository is a collection of commits. Each commit contains files-and-metadata, and the commits themselves are findable mainly by branch names, and that's pretty much all there is to a repository. There are *submodules*, where one repository refers to another repository, but this has nothing to do with clickable web buttons or popup windows or menus or whatever.

Comment: Please Check out "single-spa" https://single-spa.js.org/docs/examples 
You can create two single-spa apps and do it